# Know the pricing for additional features in salesforce?

Tags: professional-edition, pricing

How do I know the pricing for additional features in salesforce for professional edition as we want to include workflow and approval processs in PE?

Comment: Call Salesforce in your country; they'll hook you up with an AE (account executive) to disclose pricing.

Comment: Any document on this?

Comment: Prices can change over time and be negotiated based on licence quantities and features. Contact salesforce.

Comment: ... Two people with decent answers added as comments. C'mon, why won't you just add it as an answer?!

Comment: @sfdcfox in the interest of higher signal-to-noise ratio on stackexchange, sometimes I reckon it's better closing the question, than answering with ultimately a pointer to the first Google search result.

Comment: Even closing the question, it deserves an answer so people know where to go, and why it isn't relevant here. Salesforce has a pricing matrix that is affected by the number of licenses you purchase, the length of the contract, and additional features you select, and, of course, may change at any time without public notice. In other words, they should always be talking to a sales associate to get the correct pricing for their situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call Salesforce or go through their [Contact Page](http://www.salesforce.com/form/contact/contactme.jsp). They will hook you up with an AE (account executive) to disclose pricing. If you have a *specific feature* in mind, by all means revise your question and poll. Guys may answer here if they are not under NDA (non disclosure agreement).

It's about ensuring you are seeking the most appropriate feature set and solution for your requirements, not checking out your shoes and rolex watch. Eg features like [Salesforce Communities](http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/communities/) will attract different pricing depending on your volumes.

Answer (score 1):

FYI: this pricing is (not always) but often negotiable. If you are going to purchase additional products or sign an annual contract do it all at one time. This will help you get the best deal. End of the month is also beneficial because sales quotas can come into play.